# Show different objects by double clicking listbox with same name

Tags: c#, list, search, listbox

Currently I'm working on a school project where I have this class members.
The listbox shows the propeties names as in Members.Name.
The problem I have is members with the same name shows the same information in the output textbox. I kinda need a different solution let me paste in my.

```
public void OutputMember()
    {
        searchResult = MemberSearch.ByName(Program.memberList, lbmembers.Text);
        foreach (Members member in searchResult)
        {
            tboutput.Text = string.Format("Medlemsnr {0}" +
            "Namn: {1}\r\n" +
            "Eftername: {2}\r\n" +
            "Personnummer: {3}\r\n" +
            "Adress: {4}\r\n" +
            "Email: {5}\r\n" +
            "Tele:{6}\r\n\r\n\r\n",member.MemberNr, member.Name, member.SurName, member.BirthYear.outStringWithId(),
             member.Adress, member.Email, member.Tele);
```

So I understand that the problem of this is the parameters.
I just send a list of members and just the name in text.

```
public static List<Members> ByName(List<Members> memberList, string member) 
{

    List<Members> searchList = new List<Members>();


    for (int i = 0; i < memberList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (memberList[i].Name.Equals(member))
        {
            searchList.Add(memberList[i]);
        }
    }

    return searchList;
```

so the questions remains how do I view the "right" object in the output textbox by double clicking one of three equal names in the list.

Comment: if i use tboutput.Text += gives me all the members with the same name,
but that is not what im looking for,

Answer (score 0):

You have not coded what you expect the program to do.

You expect the program to display the related Member based on its position in the list.

But you have coded a search method that returns the Member based on a name match, of which there are possible duplicates.

You are also returning multiple items from the list when you only need 1, and are needlessly looping through all results only to return the last one.

You just need:

```
public void OutputMember()
{
        member = Program.memberList[lbmembers.SelectedIndex]);
        tboutput.Text = string.Format("Medlemsnr {0}" +
        "Namn: {1}\r\n" +
        "Eftername: {2}\r\n" +
        "Personnummer: {3}\r\n" +
        "Adress: {4}\r\n" +
        "Email: {5}\r\n" +
        "Tele:{6}\r\n\r\n\r\n",member.MemberNr, member.Name, member.SurName, member.BirthYear.outStringWithId(),
        member.Adress, member.Email, member.Tele);
}
```

Comment: If you're doing this in VS2015+, you can replace the string.Format with an interpolated string like tboutput.Text = $"Name: {member.Name} ...";

Comment: Thanks! worked great! 
the thing with my search method was i had a Search textbox aswell and if i for example typed "asd" i wanted  the output to show all members named "asd", that's why i had  the search method adding multiple objects.  And for less coding sake i tried to add the same search method for both the searchbox and listbox :P but apparently i only needed the index from listbox:)

Comment: If you want to implement search by text & search by index via one function you could accomplish this by function overloading. Just rename your ByName method to something like Search, and write another version that takes an int as the second parameter. The text version can return a List<Members> and the int version can return a Members. Incidentally, you might want to look at your naming convention, should the class be named Members or Member?

Comment: yeah a overload would be great makes it less code in ViewMember class. Well the name of the member class is going to be only Member. I have 2 member classes ATM cause i added an old one. So i'm trying the old one right now and it is named with an "s"